# Menu items in a Action Bar Sherlock getting darker on each search

Tags: android, animation, actionbarsherlock, menuitem

I've added a refresh button to the Menu using the following code

```
refreshItem = menu.add(Menu.NONE, REFRESH_ITEM_ID, 1, getString(R.string.refresh));
refreshItem.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_refresh));
refreshItem.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
```

When the app starts, this is the color of the refresh icon 
[image: App starting screen]

If the refresh is active, i.e., it's animated (with the following code)

```
void setupAnimation() {
    RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.36f, 
    RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    rotateAnimation.setDuration(800);
    rotateAnimation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    refreshItem.setActionView(R.layout.ic_action_bar_refresh_layout);       
    animatedIcon = (ImageView) refreshItem.getActionView();
    ...    
}

///
///
public void startRefreshingAnimation() {
    animatedIcon.startAnimation(rotateAnimation);
}
```

And then, it's gets progressively darker each time the search icon is tapped.
[image]
[image]

Note that this behaviour of the icon getting darker only happens if the icon is being animated.

Comment: Meybe it's my monitor, but all the colors vary slightly in the pics you've posted.  Now that I look more it seems like the rest of the UI got lighter.  Have you tried resetting the bar or image after the animation is complete?

Comment: It can't be done because the icon gets darker during the animation.

Comment: But I did something slightly different and it worked, I've paused the animation (using custom code) and dispatched a resume some miliseconds later, it worked :)